# Why is DEBUG not logging in the console?

Tags: node.js, express, npm, terminal

I am trying to take a tutorial on node.js and express. I'm trying to use the debug feature, but it is not logging anything to the console.

console.log works fine...but using debug() does not

I am on windows and am trying to run the app with...
set DEBUG=app ; node app.js

```
var express = require('express');
var chalk = require('chalk');
var debug = require('debug')('app');

var app = express();

app.get('/', function(req, res){

    res.send('Hello from my library app');

})

app.listen(3000, function(){
    debug(`listening on port ${chalk.blue('3000')}`);
});
```

Comment: I don't think that's how you set env vars in Windows.

Comment: Have you checked whether `DEBUG` environment is configured successfully?

Answer (score 1):

it works fine this way (when you are using  a script tag in nodejs package.json) on windows

```
"start": "set DEBUG=app & node app.js",
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var express = require('express');
var chalk = require('chalk');
var app = express();
var debug = require('debug')(app);

app.get('/', function(req, res){
  res.send('Hello from my library app');
})
app.listen(3000, function(){
  debug(`listening on port ${chalk.blue('3000')}`);
});
```